# hortonwoks sandbox hcatalog error when creating table from file

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

Hi I am trying to do tutorial from hortonworks; i was able to upload nyse.tsv.gz into sandbox hue
and view the data
but the step of creating table from this file with HCatalog fails with error  500 timeout
it seems many users ran into this problem but i could not understand the solutions suggested
can any one please advice me how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Ambri (first tab) and then disable it back.

It works for me.